# Zend from a view to another view

Tags: zend-framework, view, navigation

Im a Zend Noob,

I have it working showing the default index page [local]

> http://myzftest.test/zend_template/public/

I have created another view for my controller called about; I can see this view if I go to

> http://myzftest.test/zend_template/public/about

Now my noob question,

If I want to navigate from one view [index] to my other view [about]

how to proceed?

Im doing it like normal html:

```
<A HREF="./about">my about page</A>
```

Is this correct or is there a Zend way ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `url()` viewhelper inside your *.phtml view file:

Syntax usage:

```
$this->url(array(
             'controller' => '<yourcontroller>',
             'action' => '<youraction>'), 
          'default', true);
```

Example:

```
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
      'controller' => 'public',
      'action' => 'about'), 'default', true); ?>">
     my about page
   </a>
```